# How to send data via post method to a php file in c++?

Tags: c++, winsock

I am very new to c++. Recently I am trying to pass some data to a php file in c++ via the post method. I have tried a tutorial from [MSDN send Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740149%28VS.85%29.aspx). The code is as follows:

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

// Link with ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT 27015

int main() {

    //----------------------
    // Declare and initialize variables.
    int iResult;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    struct hostent *host;

    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct sockaddr_in clientService;

    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
    char *sendbuf = "Client: sending data test";
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN] = "";

    //----------------------
    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    //----------------------
    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ConnectSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        wprintf(L"socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    //----------------------
    // The sockaddr_in structure specifies the address family,
    // IP address, and port of the server to be connected to.
    clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
    clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( "127.0.0.1" );

    clientService.sin_port = htons( 80 );

    //----------------------
    // Connect to server.
    iResult = connect( ConnectSocket, (SOCKADDR*) &clientService, sizeof(clientService) );
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"connect failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError() );
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
  }

    //----------------------
    // Send an initial buffer
    iResult = send( ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0 );
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Bytes Sent: %d\n", iResult);

    // shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Receive until the peer closes the connection
    do {

        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if ( iResult > 0 )
            wprintf(L"Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
        else if ( iResult == 0 )
            wprintf(L"Connection closed\n");
        else
            wprintf(L"recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

    } while( iResult > 0 );


    // close the socket
    iResult = closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"close failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    WSACleanup();
    getch();
}
```

It sends data to the homepage of localhost but I would like to send data somewhere else in localhost(eg. like 'localhost/test/index.php'). If I change the code from `clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( "127.0.0.1" );` to `clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( "127.0.0.1/test/index.php" );` then I receive some errors in the exe file. But the program compiles successfully.

Please give me a solution. What should I do now?

Comment: if the php file recognizes, for example, `a` and `b`; then a string `"a=1&b=2"` may work. i'm not sure, just guessing. can you please give it a try?

Answer (score 2):

You are taking the wrong approach. The low-level socket layer only allows you to connect to a specific server (for example your local http server running on 127.0.0.1 listening on port 80) and send raw data. You need to talk HTTP with that server to really do what you want to do.

I suggest that if you are new to C++, you look at one of the many third-party libraries for C++ which allow you to "talk HTTP" with a http server - for example, [libCurl](http://curl.haxx.se/)

Comment: Have a look at the link above, it should contain code samples.